# GAN discriminator loss randomly jumps up to over 1

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, gan

I'm training my GAN, but it seems the losses (especially the discriminator loss) are quite erratic. It quickly converges to 0, but will randomly jump up to 1 or even 2-3 sometimes. I'm wondering what could cause this?

[image]

[image]